# Select all sibling divs after a child

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="main">

      <div id="one">Heading one</div>
      <div id="two">Heading two</div>
      <div id="three">Heading three</div>
      <div id="four">Heading four</div>
            :
            :
    </div>
```

I want to select the divs with respect to their DOM positions.

**For Eg:** I want to select all divs after div with `id = two` .

**NOTE : Main div is sortable , so the code should handle dynamics.**

Do I have to loop in and count total number of child divs ,,, than `(total number of child divs - position of div  with id=two )` will give how many divs are there after div with `id=two`.

Or Is there any better way ??

Comment: whats the reason for  -1 vote ? just curious

Comment: Do you want count of div?

Comment: No ! if i am not wrong I can get by using .length

Comment: yup you can get it like that.

Comment: If it is only for design purpose, you should use a CSS only solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mv1oqb2a/  And to get them: http://jsfiddle.net/mv1oqb2a/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff : yeah for design purpose , your solution is perfect , but i am doing in jquery-ui .... where i am doing calculation with respect to height and top positions for selected divs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [nextAll](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)?

```
$('#two').nextAll();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
$('#two').nextAll();
```

Please check [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

```js
$('#two').nextAll().css( "background-color", "red" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">

      <div id="one">Heading one</div>
      <div id="two">Heading two</div>
      <div id="three">Heading three</div>
      <div id="four">Heading four</div>
           
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
$("#main").sortable({
  update: function() {
    $("#main").children().removeClass("selected");
    $("#two").nextAll().addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v2ykwxfj/)